# Transpose dataframe in R and changing columns names

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I'd like to transpose this data frame:

[image: First Dataframe Rstudio]

So I use this line of code

```
perCountry <- data.frame(t(perEnergy))
```

And I get this result:

[image: Second Dataframe Rstudio]

But I'd like it without the first row (X1,X2,X3...) and with the country name at this spot.
How could I do ?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data here. Here are some excellent tips on how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you would have two different columns for each country: one for % and one for MW. It might be easier to work with if you have two different data frames:

```
percentages <- data.frame(t(perEnergy[perEnergy$a == "%",]))
MW          <- data.frame(t(perEnergy[perEnergy$a == "[MW]",]))
```

You can turn the first row into column names like this:

```
names(percentages) <- percentages[1,]
names(MW)          <- MW[1,]
```

Then remove the unwanted first row like this:

```
percentages <- percentages[-1,]
MW          <- MW[-1,]
```

Finally, if you want to stick them back together again, you will need unique row names. You might do something like this:

```
rownames(percentages) <- paste0(rownames(percentages), "_percent")
rownames(MW)          <- paste0(rownames(MW), "_MW")
```

So that finally you can join the two dataframes together:

```
perCountry <- rbind(percentages, MW)
```

Unfortunately I cannot test the above code, since you did not post any usable data in your question.